# Finding line corresponding to error in XCode debugger

Tags: objective-c, xcode

When XCode outputs an error like `'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]:etc.`, how can I find the line of code with that objectAtIndex code?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Create a new Exception breakpoint. It will usually show you where the exception is first thrown. Go to the Breakpoints tab on the left:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not a long-long-time Xcode user, but I have been using Xcode for a while now, and I didn't even knew about that option. +1 mate.

Comment: Extra tip: some of Apple’s Core Foundation classes use exceptions under the hood, and this will catch them. Edit the breakpoint to break only on Objective-C exceptions, not C++ exceptions, to avoid this.

Comment: @Zev Eisenberg I see that the default of 'Exception Breakpoint' is to only break 'On Throw' and not 'On Catch'. Isn't that enough to avoid catching those exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

Look in the lines below it,
you should have a back-trace of the methods that run by you and by the system.
There, you should find the name of the method in which it occurred in.

I've just took an existing project, and add a similar crash and purpose to illustrate this.

My method-

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];  
    self.contacts = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [ARContact loadContacts]];  
    NSLog(@"%@", self.contacts[100]); // Index 100 is outside of the array scope  
    ....  
}
```

The console log of the crash (on the bottom of Xcode)

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 100 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101a87495 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001007ec99e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101a2d745 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 213
    3   PhoneBookApp                        0x0000000100001f95 -[ViewController viewWillAppear:] + 261
    4   UIKit                               0x0000000100b1adb5 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 422
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000100b38c4d -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 707
```

Here you could see a reverse order of things as they occurred (meaning 0 is the latest thing that run, 1 is just before it, etc').

If you would look at numbers 3 and 4, You'll see that before the crash, there is a call to `NSArray`'s `objectAtIndex:` method (line 3),
And this method called from `viewWillAppear:` (line 4).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Underneath it says `'*** First throw call stack:'` and then a bunch of hex numbers.

Comment: Nice to see the stack laid out like that! My error just has the hexes followed by `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

Comment: Really? this is weird....Are you sure it doesn't just look like it is only hexes? Because Xcode's console window is usually pretty small, the stack doesn't laid out nicely as it appear in my comment above, but it looks kinda messy. Try maybe enlarging it a bit.